# View not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I got a list of buttons that looks like this[image]
The functionality that I aim for is when you press a button its background will change to another color.

```
const getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray = (selectedItems, id) => {
    selectedItems = []
    selectedItems.push(id);
    return selectedItems;
};
```

I use this function to return a list of selected items. Currently I'm only returning one item but I made it an array so I can handle multiple items in the future.
In the render function I have something like this:

```
<View style={feed_back_page_styles.buttons_wrapper}>
        {
          feedbackButtons.map((item, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity  style={this.state.selectedItems.includes(item.key)?feed_back_page_styles.pressedStyle:feed_back_page_styles.inputStyle}
                                onPress={()=>this.onButtonPress(item.key)}>
              <Text style={this.state.selectedItems.includes(item.key)?feed_back_page_styles.option_text_style_pressed:feed_back_page_styles.option_text_style}>{item.data}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        }
    </View>
```

feedbackButtons is just an array with a key and text.

The onButtonPress method looks like this:

```
    onButtonPress = (key) =>{
    updatedItems = getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray(this.state.selectedItems,key);
    this.setState({selectedItems:updatedItems},()=>console.log(this.state.selectedItems));
    console.log("Do smth else here");
  }
```

The problem is that the view does not update on state change. When I click the button the state gets updated but the view stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is wrong

```
const getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray = (selectedItems, id) => {
    selectedItems = []
    selectedItems.push(id);
    return selectedItems;
};
```

Since you are passing the `this.state.selectedItems` as 1st argument from your onButtonPress, actually its not creating new array, but using the same reference of state and state should not be modified directly, always use `setState()`.
So basically what you are doing is :

```
const getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray = (id) => {
    this.state.selectedItems = []
    this.state.selectedItems.push(id);
    return selectedItems;
};
```

Which is completely wrong and might be the actual issue. 
what you can do instead is :

```
const getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray = (selectedItems=[], id) => {
    const items = [...selectedItems]
    items.push(id);
    return items;
};
```

and then :

```
    onButtonPress = (key) =>{
        const updatedItems = getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray(key); // since currently you want to keep only 1 item in the list
/* Incase more than 1 items, you can then use this
const updatedItems = getUpdatedSelectedItemsArray(this.state.selectedItems, key); 
*/   
        this.setState({selectedItems:updatedItems},()=>console.log(this.state.selectedItems));
        console.log("Do smth else here");
      }
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Also, if you can share your component, it can help if there is some other issue with your component like if you are using PureComponent.